# Cancel Processing Order Triggered Event. Magento2

Tags: magento2, cancel-orders

I'm trying to get an Event after canceling Order now for COD or Pending Orders `order_cancel_after` Event is working fine but for Online Payment or Processing Orders same Event is not working I've tried `sales_order_payment_cancel_invoice` Event but same that event didnt work.. Now I want to know which Event Triggers on canceling Processing Order. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i've seen there's multiple events for the order cancel,

1. order_cancel_after
2. sales_order_invoice_cancel
3. sales_order_payment_cancel_invoice
4. sales_order_payment_cancel_creditmemo
5. sales_order_payment_cancel_invoice
6. sales_order_creditmemo_cancel

If none of those fits you i think you should use the sales_order_save_after event, and check if the new order status differs from the old order status and then do your business logic,

sales_order_save_after and sales_order_state_change_before

on those 2 event's you can go check the new status of the order.

Comment: `sales_order_save_after` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

There's this one event: `sales_order_save_after`, it triggers **a lot!**

You can add restriction to your observer to prevent it running too many times (such as check if status is cancel)